How the number of agents in a population affect the number of messages received by another agent type when using sendToAll?
I built a model in which Agent type A goes through statecharts based on receiving a message from Agent type B. The model works, but I don't understand what assumptions the software is making.
For example, lets have 100 Agents Type A and 10 Agents type B. If Agent Type B uses (message) sendToAll, what is the software interpreting? Is every Agent type B sending messages to the 100 Agents Type A?
NEXT: Lets suppose Agents Type A have three (3) consecutive states: X. Y, Z. They are all triggered by receiving the same message by Agent type B. If we consider we have the same number of agents as the previous exercise, Are Agents Type B sending messages to all in all state charts at the same time? Or is the software prioritizing states ( first x, then Y, then Z)?
NEXT: in case the answer to the questions above is that Agent type B sends all the messages to all Agents A at the same time, is there a way to limit how many messages Agents Type B send in each cycle?
The model also includes a parameter and the simulation shows heterogeinity in the results, but I don't know if this is because of the parameter or because of the relationship between the number of both agents (and the sendtoall function), or both.
I tried with different number of agents and I do get different results, so I'm guessing there is a something going on with messages and it is related to the number of agents sending the message and the number of agents available to receive such messages, but I don't understand what the software assumes this.

First: sendToAll will send a message to all the agents that are in the same environment as the agent that is sending the message (including itself)
So in your example, if one agent type B uses sendToAll (which means the sendToAll function is being used inside the type B agent), assuming that both type A and type B are agents that live in Main
ALL agents type B and all agents type A will receive the message.
if all type B agents are sending a message, then all agents will receive messages from all type B agents... so an agent type A will receive 100 messages if there 100 type B agents.
Second, all messages that are going to be sent are queued by AnyLogic, and it's not possible for you to know exactly in what order they are going to happen.
If you want to limit the number of messages to send, you cannot use sendToAll, instead you can do something like
for(int i=0;i<limit;i++){
   send("your message",agentA(i));
}

